# Adding a field query in sql

Tags: oracle, alter

I want to add a field `total` to the `Registration` table and to ensure that the value of `total` column is less than the value of `count`.

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE Registration
ADD CONSTRAINT total
CHECK(total < count);
```

or else I wanted to add the column first like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Registration
  ALTER COLUMN total NUMBER(10);
```

I don't know how to check the condition after this.

Comment: Keep in mind MySQL versions lower then 8.0.16 simply ignores the [CHECK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).. So if have a MySQL version lower then 8.0.16 you would have to use a VIEW with check option which is the best option to emulate/simulate CHECK ..

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:mysql], but you use the `NUMBER` data type, which is not used by MySQL (you may be using Oracle?). Please make sure to tag your question with the correct RDBMS product you are using.

Comment: Count of what? Or is `count` another column name?